# Can lazy loaded features communicate state between features with ngrx in Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, lazy-loading, ngrx

If I have an app that uses **lazy loading**, and also using **ngrx** to manage state, I have a state instance for each feature with its own reducers, actions, etc.  So for example:

```
product-feature
    product-edit
    product-add
    product-admin
    state
        product.reducer.ts
        product.actions.ts
        product.effects.ts
        product.index.ts
customer-feature
    customer-edit
    customer-add
    customer-admin
    state
        customer.reducer.ts
        customer.actions.ts
        customer.effects.ts
        customer.index.ts
```

With this structure, my main question is can the state between `product-feature` communicate and use the state between `customer-feature`?  If I, as a user, go to `customer-feature`, but the `customer-feature` needed some state information from the `product-feature`, would it still render and get the data even though the `product-feature` was never created because the user did not go to it (via lazy loading)?

Most examples I see online deal with ngrx as one `AppState` and don't do lazy loading, and the lazy loading examples I see that do communication between components are parent/child.  Some articles I read say that you need to extend the app state to include the feature state, as the feature state cannot be referenced in the app state.  The instance I am wondering is communicating state between sibling features.  Is this possible with ngrx via lazy loading?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ngrx will merge the new state of the lazy loaded module with the current state, and that will happen only when you navigate to one of the routes of your lazy loaded module, so if your product-feature is not loaded, you will not have access to it's store.

i suggest to move the part you need in your customer-feature, or you can create a shared module for that

Comment: would it matter if I `PreloadAllModules` or have a custom preloading strategy?

Comment: if you Preload all modules you will lose the benefit of lazy loading, you can make customer-feature a child of  product-feature, in that case product-feature will access customer-feature. another solution is to create a new shared module for shared stuffs

Comment: Found this article which seems to suggest it is possible, you would just need to create a default reducer at the app state level that merges all of the feature states at once: https://medium.com/youngers-consulting/ngrx-tips-part-1-module-setup-with-lazy-loading-5dc8994b5a2d

Comment: But with `export function defaultReducer<T>(state: T) { return state; }` you are not going to get any data in product state. The obvious answer is to disconnect product state from the lazy loaded product module. Of course, depends on where the logic lives - is it all in actions, or does a `product.service` populate product state?

Comment: @eric99, the `product.service` would populate the state initially.

Comment: Well, not if you have `product.service` in the lazy loaded product module (assuming you want to maintain lazy loading). Essentially, I think you need to stop using ngrx's `StoreModule.forFeature('products', productsReducer)` and include products in `StoreModule.forRoot(compositeReducer)`.